# Action of $D^1 L$ on V is zero for an irreducible representation $V$ of a solvable Lie algebra $L$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

I have already shown via Lie's theorem that a finite dimensional irreducible representation $(V,R)$ of a solvable Lie algebra $L$ over an algebraically closed field with characteristic $0$ has dimension $\dim V=1$.

Now I want to see that $[L,L]$ acts as zero on $V$.

I tried two things: Working with an common eigenvector for $\text{im}(R)$ and using the very definition, i.e. $[x,y].v=x.(y.v)-y.(x.v)=R(x)(R(y)(v))-R(y)(R(x)(v))=...$

Both ways couldn't be finished by me.

Comment: Looks easy. In a Lie algebra representation the action of $[x,y]$ is the commutator of the actions of $x$ and $y$. But all linear operators on a $1$-dimensional space commute.

Comment: So how wouöd you go on after $[x,y].v=x.(y.v)-y.(x.v)=R(x)(R(y)(v))-R(y)(R(x)(v))=...$?

Comment: $...=0$ since $R(x)$ and $R(y)$ are scalar matrices.

Comment: Why are they scalar matrices?

Comment: Because you said in the question that $\dim V=1$.

Comment: I really don't get you point. Do you want to make an answer?

Comment: When you act by linear transformations on a vector space of dimension $n$, you get an $n\times n$ matrix. So, on a 1-dimensional vector space, you get a $1\times1$ matrix. Also known as a scalar.